# in Sequelize I can't use the create method in a model that has many - to -many relationship with another model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this relation:

```
AppCategory.hasMany(AppCategoryType);
AppCategoryType.belongsTo(AppCategory, { constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
```

I tried to get the AppCategoryTypes with the include method it works perfect:

```
const appCategory = await AppCategory.findOne({
        where: { id: req.body.categoryId },
        include: {
            model: AppCategoryType,
        }
    });
```

**output:**.

> {
> "id": 1,
> "image": "app-category-2023-03-05T17:49:24.040Z.jpg",
> "nameEn": "Clothes",
> "nameAr": "Clothes Ar",
> "query": null,
> "app category types": []
> }

but when I'm trying to make like this:

```
 const appCategoryType = await appCategory.createAppCategoryType({
        titleEn: 'New Category Type',
        titleAr: 'نوع جديد للفئة',
    });
```

I'm getting appCategory.createAppCategoryType is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

What I am getting from your question is like, if you want to create new record, you can do the following sequelize query in nodejs.

```
try {
  const record = await AppCategoryType.create({
      titleEn: 'New Category Type',
      titleAr: 'نوع جديد للفئة',
  });
  console.log(record);
  res.send('Record created');
} catch (error) {
   res.send(error);
}
```